# Problem using pooling, database wrapper and transactions with mySql database

Tags: mysql, wrapper, connection-pooling

I have previously used this DB wrapper and transaction function with success.
However, since I experienced problems of being disconnected from database host, I began fiddling with pooling.
It seemed to do the trick, but I don't know if I'm doing things right altogether. I'm not very experienced.

0: As it is now no errors are produced.

1: Does the code look ok?

2: But most importantly: I can't seem to figure out how to access the results of a query (see below) (or does query simply hang)?

```
// Pool settings (pool of connections).
const poolCnf = {
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: 'myHost',
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPass',
    database: 'myDB'
};

// Creating a pool for connections.
const pool = mysql.createPool(poolCnf);

// Instancing the wrapper, ready for use.
const DB = DbWrapper(pool);


// Using wrapper function which handles different actions on the pool connection.
function DbWrapper(pool) {
    return {
      async query( sql, args ) {
        return await pool.query.call(pool, sql, args);
      },
      async close() {
        return await pool.end;
      },
      async beginTransaction() {
        return await pool.beginTransaction;
      },              
      async commit() {
        return await pool.commit;
      },
      async rollback() {
        return await pool.rollback;
      }
    };
}

// Transaction helper function to avoid boiler plate code.
async function DbTransAction( db, callback ) {
    try {
      await db.beginTransaction();
      await callback();
      await db.commit();
    } 
    catch ( err ) {
      await db.rollback();
      throw err;
    } 
    finally {
      await db.close();
    }
}

// ============================
let rowsA;
let rowsB;
let queryA =`
    SELECT * FROM games;
`;

let queryB =`
    SELECT * FROM sceneData;
`;    

DbTransAction(DB,  async () => {
    rowsA = await DB.query(queryA);
});
DbTransAction(DB,  async () => {
    rowsB = await DB.query(queryB);
});
console.log("rowsA:" + JSON.stringify(rowsA));
console.log("rowsB:" + JSON.stringify(rowsB));
```

The simple query does it never return ?
Since the rows are undefined ?

Console output:

```
UX_Game_NodeServer> node app
rowsA:undefined
rowsB:undefined
```

Comment: Note: In the code above I made 2 queries, and in other parts 3 queries => On my hosting site, I can see there is exactly 5 active connections. Does it mean the queries isn't completed? I can create tables, and insert rows, no problem. But I can't seem to retrieve rows again?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `await` before each *DbTransAction* call, currently those calls return immediately and so *rowA* and *rowB* remain undefined.
Otherwise, you can move console.log call within *DbTransAction* callback.

Also in your DBWrapper you need to add parentheses after `end`, `beginTransaction`,  `commit`, `rollback`:

```js
async beginTransaction() {
   return await pool.beginTransaction();
},
```

Also the query call can be like this:

```js
await pool.query(sql, args);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) but I don't understand why I have to do that, I already wait with rowsA = await DB.query(queryA); ? I tried enclosing my 2 queries in an async function and then placing await before each DbTransaction, but it was still undefined. And if I place console.log inside callback I get some warning : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON